# Encoded html element

Tags: html, encoding

I know that I can use hex in urlencode to specify the source of element.
Is there any way to use hex (maybe, url or base64) for common elements?
For example this construction works 
`<iframe s%72%63`
but this doesn't
`<ifr%2bame s%72%63`

I have to use pure html without js functions.

Comment: That's not clear: `<iframe s%72%63="foo.html">` as HTML markup won't set your iframe's `src` attribute but its `s%72%63` one, literally. So how do you make this work if not with js?

Comment: I mean not using js for binding functions or getting element id. It doesn't matter for what element or how it used but `s%72%63` as a `src` works properly with iframe or img. After all this questions most about encoding/decoding rules while parsing a page.

Comment: How does this work? How are you using this partially encoded string so that it gets decoded? As I said, in html markup, it won't work, so you are obviously either using it in a dataURI, or some other js manipulation. We need to know where you use it. At page parsing, there is no percent-encoding decoding process. There will be [HTML-entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) decoding, but since it is made to render special characters used in the markup language, as their actual character representation, you won't be able to use it as markup.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gvcmjLep/

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem - one where you describe what you've done to solve a problem rather than the actual problem itself. This tends to attract unhelpful solutions since the imagined way to solve the actual problem is in itself flawed - no implementation of a flawed (read: wrong) approach can be satisfactory. So then, what problem are you trying to solve with the use of encoded anything?

Comment: @Kaiido Like this, for example 
`<iframe s%72%63=1.xyz onload=window.location="http://www.example.com">`

This is mostly the theoretical question. I'm trying to understand rules of decoding for now. If the answer is "no", so be it.